# Converting Virgin Australia flights into AirNZ Airpoints

Tags: loyalty-programs, air-new-zealand, virgin-australia

Evidently, Virgin Australia flights can be used to earn AirNZ airpoints, something I wish I'd found out a few months earlier so that I could have claimed a flight last year.

However, I'm struggling to find any table or chart or anything indicating how many AirNZ airpoints each flight will get me.

For example, I might want to know if I flew business class from MEL to ADL return, how many AirNZ airpoints would that get me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Virgin Australia Earn Airpoints Table](http://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/airpoints-virgin-australia-earn-chart) is linked from ANZ's [Earning Airports](http://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/earning-airpoints-dollars) page.

Since MEL-ADL is 399 miles (~642km), you would earn 20 Airpoints in business class one-way or 40 round trip.

> On trans-Tasman flights if you book an Air New Zealand flight, with an NZ flight number (eg NZ101 or NZ7000), even if it is operated by Virgin Australia you will earn Airpoints Dollars based on the [Airpoints Dollars Earned on Air New Zealand Flights table](http://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/airpoints-dollars-earned-on-airnz-from-24-july-2012).
>
> If you travel on Virgin Australia flight numbers (eg DJ101 or DJ8000) across the Tasman or on a flight operated by Virgin Australia domestically within Australia you will earn Airpoints Dollars based on the [Airpoints Dollars Earned on Virgin Australia Flights](http://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/airpoints-virgin-australia-earn-chart) table.
>
> If you travel on any other Virgin Australia flight, excluding flights to or from the Pacific Islands, you will earn based on the [Airpoints Dollars Earned on Partner Flights](http://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/airpoints-airline-partner-earning-chart-from-1-june) table.